How to avoid a Cloud Run Functions 403 Forbidden Error?
I have implemented some functions using Cloud Functions (now Cloud Run Functions). Recently, I deployed a new function but encountered an authentication or permissions issue that I have not been able to resolve. The function was successfully deployed to Cloud Run Functions.
The problem is that when I try to invoke the function from Postman (or the web), I get the following error:
403 Forbidden  
Your client does not have permission to get URL /apiNotifications/hello-world from this Server.

The Service Account used by Firebase has the Editor role. Additionally, I tried adding the Cloud Functions Invoker permission as suggested in the documentation for this type of error (Cloud Functions troubleshooting documentation), but the issue persists.
The API code has been simplified to the following:
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = express();

app.get('/hello-world', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

How can I identify exactly where the problem is?
How can I resolve the 403 Forbidden error when running a Cloud Run Function (1st Gen)?

When you invoke the Function from Postman (or the web), the service is expecting you to authenticate by providing credentials as part of the request typically a header Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}. You can test this by generating an identity token (gcloud auth print-identity-token) and using the value that results as the value for {TOKEN} when making a request of the function. Adjusting IAM permissions is only relevant when you're using another Google Cloud services (e.g. another Cloud Run service) to invoke the Function.

It's unclear from your question but it's possible that your Cloud Run (Function) deployment has been revised to require authentication and/or you've dropped the public (unauthenticated) access somehow. See Allowing public (unauthenticated) access for pointers.
